# Similarity between 2 columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, similarity

I have a dataframe with a couple of columns, two of which are `Artist_x` and `Artist_y`. I would like to find the similarity between these two columns and get the similarity percentage as a new column. I think I can use difflib but not sure exactly how.

I currently have:

```
mergednew['SimilarityArtist'] = mergednew.apply(lambda row: similar(row['Artist_x'], row['Artist_y']), axis=1)
```

Comment: What type of similarity? Number of exact matches? Cosine distance between artist names? ...

Comment: Are they text of the artists' names?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find *exact matches* or *partial matches*?

Exact matches can be found using:

```
num_matches = []
total_items = len(column_A)
for i in range(len (column_A)):
    if column_A == column_B:
        num_matches.append (1)
        print(num_matches/total_items)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try following code:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
Artist_x=Artist_x.reshape(1,-1)
Artist_y=Artist_y.reshape(1,-1)
cosine_similarity(Artist_x,Artist_y)
```

You will get some value with range between 0 to 1. 1 is for maximum similarity and 0 for minimum.